# Stripe milliseconds portion of time

Tags: awk

I would like to Stripe milliseconds from portion of time data.
Here is my try 
Output

```
datetime='09:57:37.000000000'
hello='Hello World'
echo $datetime $hello |awk '{print sub(/\..+/,"",$datetime),$hello}'

Actual Output
1 09:57:37

Expected Output
09:57:37 Hello World
```

- Any ideas how i achieve my expected output ?
- Apologies forgot to mention i cannot use '.' as the field separator as the    original   problem has many fields in it

Comment: What was the reasoning behind your attempt?

Comment: I wanted to simplify the example before i post it here but ended up oversimplifying things.I have made the correction to the question now

Comment: No, I mean the reasoning behind `echo $datetime $hello |awk '{print sub(/\..+/,"",$datetime),$hello}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '09:57:37.000000000 Hello World'  |awk '{gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$1)}1
09:57:37 Hello World
```

Delete Literal dot followed by anything ,in First column. (thanks  NeronLeVelu)

Comment: Should be the right approach! `++`, `gensub()` could be used, but this is far simpler

Comment: I have many other fields there like $1,$2 etc which needs to printed out too.Something like echo $datetime $fname, $name |awk '{print sub(/\..+/,"",$datetime),$datetime}' but only time should be striped from datetime

Comment: Please add example of input data.

Comment: Hi PS Apologies mate i have added an example to the input data

Comment: @jhon.smith ,check my update in answer. Hope you can use it by changing the column number in `gsub`

Comment: ??? `[^$]` mean no `$` sign, not *not the end* because it is in a class regex. It work becasue there is no `$` as good as if you put [^lazydog]. At least yuou shoud use `/\.[0-9]*/`. I prefer, in this case,  `/[.0-9]{3,}/` (with `--re-interval` on last gawk).

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
 echo $datetime |awk -F'[. ]' '{print $1}'
 09:57:37
```

**OR**

```
egrep -o "[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]" <<< $datetime
09:57:37
```

**OR**

```
sed 's/.[0-9]*$//' <<<$datetime
09:57:37
```

**OR**

```
awk '{sub(/\.[0-9]*$/,"")}1' <<<$datetime
09:57:37
```

Comment: Apologies Vipin i cannot use '.' as the field separator as there many fields which are separated by spaces too

Comment: Sure we can add "." and " "(Space) in field seperator. using -F'[. ]'

Comment: just a remark on sed `sed 's/^\([^.]*\)[.0-9]\{2,\}/\1/'` because sed take the LONGEST possible, if there is a longer `.01234561213` in the line, it remove the second one, not the time as expected. Assuming there is always a time at start like sample. Same concept for the grep

Comment: Thanks @NeronLeVelu for your Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
datetime='09:57:37.000000000'
echo $datetime |awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave regexps out of it:

```
$ echo 09:57:37.000000000 | awk '{print substr($0,1,8)}'
09:57:37
```

Or after reading the problem completely:

```
$ awk -v datetime="$datetime" -v hello="$hello" '
BEGIN { print substr(datetime,1,8), hello }'
09:57:37 Hello World
```

You bring variables from the shell to awk `awk -v datetime="$datetime"`. `sub` modifies variables inplace so you can't print the result of it like `print sub()...` but instead you should `sub(... var); print var` or use some other approach like the `print substr()`above.

Then again you don't need awk for that, you can do that in shell, bash expected:

```
$ echo ${datetime%.*} $hello
09:57:37 Hello World
```